# ArrayAdapter makes multiple copies of screen

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-arrayadapter

I'm learning how to use ArrayAdapter and attempted to use [this code](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1516) to see ArrayAdapter's functionality.

It seems like it makes multiple versions of the screen like [this](http://i.gyazo.com/50bd2d5596e6a718c091b2f4896243d6.png) and I have no clue why. Can anybody help? Thank you!

Here is my code!

```
public class DragAndDropActivity extends ListActivity {

TextView selection;
String[] items = { "this", "is", "a", "really",
        "silly", "list" };
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.drag_and_drop_test);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this,
            android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,
            items));
    selection=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.selection);
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    String text = " position:" + position + "  " + items[position];
    selection.setText(text);
}
}
```

and here is the layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/selection"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ff0000cc"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Why are you using `simple_expandable_list_item_1`?

Comment: @Squonk i was mostly just following the example code, I figured that a simple layout with just a textview would work. is that line the reason?

Comment: I don't really know what sort of effect you're trying to achieve but a standard `ListView` should normally have one list item for each 'slot'. The layout you're using is for an `ExpandableListView` which is designed to have groups (parents) and each group has a child list. Try using `simple_list_item_1` (I think that's the right name).

Comment: @Squonk i guess the question is why it displays as an amalgam of colors and copies of the same lines instead of how it should display? I changed to a `simple_list_item_1` and [this was the display](http://i.gyazo.com/de90625cb9ea7fd8a84cfa26cf41db8e.png)

is it a setting on my phone or my code that is causing it perhaps?